# Which version of SQL Server CE does WP 8 supports?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I was following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) example on MSDN which creates a SQL Server CE database file (`.sdf`) from code.

I was wondering what is the version of SQL Server CE database here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version on the device is compatible with version 3.5 on the desktop, but the Windows Phone version of the database engine has some of the features from version 4.0, namely enhanced encryption and support for OFFSET and FETCH paging syntax.